# Changing XML data source of Crystal Report

Tags: c#, xml, ado.net, crystal-reports

I created a Crystal Report and connected it to an XML file at `C:\SomeDir\Data.xml`.

At runtime, I may need to put the data in `C:\SomeOtherDir\Data.xml`.

The code I have so far looks like this:

```
ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
report.Load("Report.rpt");
PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
PageSettings pageSettings = printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
report.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pageSettings, false);
```

That will print the report with the data at `C:\SomeDir\Data.xml`. I want it to print the data at `C:\SomeOtherDir\Data.xml`.

How can I do this?

Comment: Could you please post the code for loading the report from xml?

Comment: @Urik: There is no code. The report is bound to the XML file.

Comment: But aren't you using something like rpt.Database.Tables[0].SetDataSource(ds_xml); ?

Comment: @Urik: No. The above code is all I have report-related.

Comment: So I think you might need that in order to do this thing you're asking for. Something like loading the data from the xml into a dataset and then feeding that to the crystal report through  "SetDataSource" @Kendall

Comment: @Urik: Would that work exactly the same as connecting to the XML file? My data is a little strange, in that the XML root element is the single record of data I need. Can DataSource handle it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13222/discussion-between-urik-and-kendall-frey)

Comment: @Urik: I face same problem. In crystal report you can not dynamically assign the Datasource from code behind.

Answer (score 1):

```
ReportDocument report = new ReportDocument();
report.Load("Report.rpt");

DataSet reportData = new DataSet();
reportData.ReadXml(@"C:\SomeOtherDir\Data.xml");
report.SetDataSource(reportData);

PrinterSettings printerSettings = new PrinterSettings();
PageSettings pageSettings = printerSettings.DefaultPageSettings;
report.PrintToPrinter(printerSettings, pageSettings, false);
```

If the schema of the XML changes, you will need to open the report in the CR editor and "verify database" to update the schema it is bound to, or it will throw the mysterious "Logon Failed" error.

Answer (score 0):

In Java if I wish to substitute a fresh set of data at run time I will typically load in that data (be it a result set from a db or xml or whatever) and push it in via rpt.Database.Tables.setDataSource passing the 'table alias' of the original data so CR knows what to overwrite. It'll likely be similar in C#. You might want to brush up on that, try it out and then come back with more questions.

Answer (score 0):

```
Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared
Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
Imports BL

Public Class frmRptViewer
    Dim strReportName As String
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Public bl As New BL.InvoiceBL
    Private Sub configureCrystalReports()
        Dim strReportName As String
        Try
            strReportName = "Inv"
            ds = bl.FillHDDT(TrnCode)
            Dim strReportPath As String = Application.StartupPath & "\Reports\" & strReportName & ".rpt"
            Dim rptDocument As New CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument
            ds.WriteXml(Application.StartupPath & "\xmlFiles\INVOICE.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
            rptDocument.Load(strReportPath)

            Dim crpConnectionInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfo
            With crpConnectionInfo
                .ServerName = Application.StartupPath & "\xmlFiles\INVOICE.xml"
                .DatabaseName = "NewDataset"
                .UserID = ""
                .Password = ""
            End With

            Dim tblCurrent As Table
            Dim crpTableLogOnInfo As New CrystalDecisions.Shared.TableLogOnInfo()
            For Each tblCurrent In rptDocument.Database.Tables
                tblCurrent.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.ServerName = Application.StartupPath & "\xmlFiles\INVOICE.xml"
                tblCurrent.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.DatabaseName = "NewDataset"
                tblCurrent.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.UserID = ""
                tblCurrent.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Password = ""
                tblCurrent.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo.Type = CrystalDecisions.Shared.ConnectionInfoType.MetaData
            Next
            rptDocument.Database.Tables(0).SetDataSource(ds.Tables("Table"))
            rptDocument.Database.Tables(1).SetDataSource(ds.Tables("Table1"))

            crptViewer.ShowRefreshButton = False
            crptViewer.ShowCloseButton = False
            crptViewer.ShowGroupTreeButton = False
            crptViewer.ReportSource = rptDocument
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need from begining,
consider you need print DataGridView  data show in Crystelreport using XML

```
**(This is very helpful if you not using any database)**
```

1. First make Data table
2. Then Add data to Data table (Here add from DataGridview)
3. Make XML file
4. Run Report

Here Sample Code

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
 dt.Columns.Add("Item_Id", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("Categry", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("Item_Name", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("Unit_Price", typeof(double));
 dt.Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(int));
 dt.Columns.Add("Discount", typeof(string));
 dt.Columns.Add("Total_Payable", typeof(double));
  foreach (DataGridViewRow dgr in DGVsell.Rows) 
 {
   dt.Rows.Add(dgr.Cells[0].Value, dgr.Cells[1].Value, dgr.Cells[2].Value, dgr.Cells[3].Value, dgr.Cells[4].Value, dgr.Cells[5].Value, dgr.Cells[6].Value);
 }
 ds.Tables.Add(dt);
 ds.WriteXmlSchema("Bill.xml");
```

**note** If had error making Xml change *App.config* file as follow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  </startup>-->
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

After maked xml file , you can call to the Crystel report

```
 frmreport obj = new frmreport(); //load report viwer form
 obj.ShowDialog();
```

in report viwer

```
crBill cr = new crBill();
cr.SetDataSource(frmSell.ds);
crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cr;
crystalReportViewer1.RefreshReport();
crystalReportViewer1.Refresh();
```